# MongoDB relationships for objects

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, database-design, mongodb

Please excuse my english, I'm still trying to master it.

I've started to learn MongoDB (coming from a C# background) and I like the idea of what is MongoDB. I have some issues with examples on the internet.

Take the popular blog post / comments example. Post has none or many Comments associated with it. I create Post object, add a few Comment objects to the IList in Post. Thats fine.

Do I add that to just a "Posts" Collection in MonoDB or should I have two collections - one is blog.posts and blog.posts.comments?

I have a fair complicated object model, easiest way to think of it is as a Banking System - ours is mining. I tried to highlight tables with square brackets.

**[Users]** have one or many **[Accounts]** that have one or many **[Transactions]** which has one and only one **[Type]**. **[Transactions]** can have one or more **[Tag]** assigned to the transaction. **[Users]** create their own **[Tags]** unique to that user account and we sometimes need to offer reporting by those tags (Eg. for May, tag drilling-expense was $123456.78).

For indexing, I would have thought seperating them would be good but I'm worried it is bad practice this thinking from old RBDMS days.

In a way, its like the blog example. I'm not sure if I should have 1 **[Account]** Collection and persist all information there, or have an intermediate step that splits it up to seperate collections.

The other related query is, when you persist back and forth, do you usually get back *everything* associated with that record - even if not required or do you limit?

Comment: It seems to me your data model is heavily relational. I don't think a document-based data-store is a fit for it(see @Hightechrider's response). NoSQL means 'Non-Relational data-store', and NOT 'SQL Alternative'. That is why NoSQL is a bull-shit marketing term for such systems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends.

It depends on how many of each of these type of objects you expect to have.  Can you fit them all into a single MongoDB document for a given User?  Probably not.

It depends on the relationships - is user-Account a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship?  If it's one to many and the number of Accounts is small you might chose to put them in an IList on a User document.

You can still model relationships in MongoDB with separate collections BUT there are no joins in the database so you have to do that in code.  Loading a User and then loading their Accounts might be just fine from a performance perspective.

You can index INTO arrays on documents.  Don't think of an Index as just being an index on a simple field on a document (like SQL).  You can use, say, a Tag collection on a document and index into the tags.  (See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-Arrays)

When you retrieve or write data you can do a partial read and a partial write of any document.  (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)

And, finally, when you can't see how to get what you want using collections and indexes, you might be able to achieve it using map reduce.  For example, to find all the tags currently in use sorted by their frequency of use you would *map* each document emitting the tags used in it, and then you would *reduce* that set to get the result you want.  You might then store the result of that map reduce permanently and only up date it when you need to.

*One further concern: You mention calculating totals by tag.  If you want accounting-quality transactional consistency, MongoDB might not be the right choice for you.  "Eventual-consistency" is the name of the game for NoSQL data stores and they generally aren't a good fit for financial transactions.  For example, it doesn't matter if one user sees a blog post with 3 comments while another sees 4 because they hit different replica copies that aren't in sync yet, but for a financial report, that kind of consistency does matter - your report might not add up!*