# Storing relationship data in mongodb

Tags: ruby, database-design, mongodb, relational-database

Say we want to implement a following relationship in mongodb, between 2 users.

But you also want to store some attribute about the relationship (like time created, or referred by)

In a traditional relationship model, you would have a relationship table where these attributes are stored (indexed by the 2 user ids)

How would you do so in Mongodb?

If you define the relationship in the User table, it is simple, but i am not sure where the attribute data will go

```
class User
  references_many :follows, :inverse_of => :followers ,:class_name=>"User"
  references_many :followers,  :inverse_of => :follows ,:class_name=>"User"
```

Comment: Very similar question here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253496/mongodb-relationships-for-objects

Comment: I do not think the question is similar at all. I am asking a very specific question about where the relationship data should be stored

Answer (score 1):

You would store the User Ids inside the User model as an array. e.g

```
class User
  ...
  key :follower_ids, Array, :typecast => 'ObjectId'
  many :followers, :in => :follower_ids
```

Comment: but where will i store the data about the relationship, not the object?