# MongoDB :: Database Design

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB. I have Users and I have Things. A user can follow or like those things and he can also follow another user. **Where should I store the list of likes and follows?** In SQL that was a JOIN call with a table of following / type / followed, but in Mongo, well... I just don't know.

**Options I think of**:

1. A collection with following / type / followed, each has a DBref
2. Storing the data twice, once in the users collection and once in the things collection. The maintainability of this looks bad and so does querying.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600007/mongodb-should-you-still-provide-ids-linking-to-other-collections-to-or-just-inc which is almost the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest option 1 since you might need to do some computation.
Map reduce works only on one collection for now. It's also easier to provide stats.
I don't really use DBref but this approach has owrked pretty well so far for me.