# MongoDB Tables Scheme Design -Best Practice. Use Master Documents(like in master tables rdbms) or Not

Tags: database-design, mongodb

**Background :**
I am prototyping use of MongoDB in my project where i am using some master tables to store definitions and using these keys in data tables.
my few master tables are

```
Class Master_Feed_Provider { int key;
string feed_provider_name 
string address }

Class Master_File_Types {int id;
string type }
```

My data table is

```
Class Data_Feeds {int id, 
int file_type_key , int feed_provider_key ,
DateTime time }
```

**here i use feed_provider_key to link the details from master_feed_provider

So here my doubt is mongoDb does support this kind of design , but should i go for this design or i should just keep full details of feed_provider and file_types  in my data_feed table entries in place of only keys and fetch info using joins ?

Keeping full details in my data tables (in place of only key ) will increase the data size.
and Keeping keys and using joins to link details will result in extra db operations. 
So which way is better here  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: there is **no** "*This is the right way to do it in mongo"* unlike in RDBMS. Every decision made should be based in common sense. This is the link describing possible design decisions: [link](http://speakerdeck.com/u/mongodb/p/schema-design-kyle-banker-10gen). As it tells there are 2 options:
masterfeeds:

1)

```
masterfeeds:

{ _id: idValue,
    name: nameValue,
    masterFileTypes:[typeId1, typeId2, typeId3]}

masterFileTypes:
  { _id: idValue,
    Type: typeValue,
    masterFeeds:[mfId1, mfId2, mfId3]}
```

2)

```
masterfeeds:
      { _id: idValue,
        name: nameValue,
        masterFileTypes: [typeId1, typeId2, typeId3]}

masterFileTypes:
  { _id: idValue,
    Type: typeValue}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using `ObjectId` values for your keys.

Your question is somewhat hard to understand but overall MongoDB can support a traditional relational model BUT because there are no joins in the database you have to do them in your application and that typically means multiple requests to the database.

Instead you typically want to denormalize the data somewhat and perhaps store a copy of the fields that you need so you can satisfy the request in fewer round-trips.

See [MongoDB: Should you still provide IDs linking to other collections to or just include collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600007/mongodb-should-you-still-provide-ids-linking-to-other-collections-to-or-just-in/4601052#4601052)

Comment: This post is helpful. but i am still confuse as if i keep all the details (which will be repetitive info ) in my data tables my db size will increase ( i can use simple key to link the detail and use joins). and if use keys only than i have to apply joins which monngodb doesnot support , i have to make extra db calls.
**i have edited the original post. it should be clear now

Answer (score 0):

It basically boils down the whether to embed (subdocument) or link(another collection document)?

Have a look at [how to structure many-to-many relationships in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592801/how-to-structure-many-to-many-relationships-in-mongoose/13595155#13595155) for pros and cons of each approach.