# MongoMapper: how do I create a model like this

Tags: ruby, mongodb, logic, mongomapper, database

Suppose we have two models, Task and User.
So a user can have many tasks and tasks should be able to have many users too. But, a task should also have a unique creator who is also a user.

Exemple:

A task in this context is like this:
Task ID, Task Creator, Users who should do the task

User_1 creates a task and he is then the creator.
User_1 specifies User_2 and User_3 as users who should do the task. So these two last users are not creators of task.

How do I create this models so that if I have a task object, I can find it's creator and users who should complete it. And how do I do, if I have a user, to find all tasks he created and all tasks he should complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB relationships for objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253496/mongodb-relationships-for-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a many-to-many relationship between the Tasks and Users, and you need an additional one-to-many relationship between Users and Tasks, pointing to the creator (User).

Something along these lines: (I usually use Mongoid, so double-check the syntax for the relations in the MongoMapper API - link below.. you might to manually specify :foreign_key and :class)

The idea is that you have two relationships between the models, one which models the many-to-many relationship
with which you get either to the `assigned_users` or `assigned_tasks`, and a one-to-many relationship with which you get to either the `creator` of a task, or the `created_tasks` for a given user.  If you chose these names for the relationships, it will be clear which is which.

```
class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :title, String , :required => true

  key :user_ids , Array
  has_many :users, :in => user_ids     # , :as => :assigned_users

  key :creator_id , ObjectId
  belongs_to: user, :as => :creator

end

class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key: name, String, :required => true

  has_many :tasks           # , :as => :assigned_tasks

  has_many :tasks, :as => :created_tasks
end
```

See:

http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/associations.html

Comment: Yah, you do have to specify `:foreign_key` and `:class`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer suggested by Tilo is correct about how to model the data, but the example code is incorrect and will not work.  The `:as` option is for [polymorphic associations](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/associations.html#polymorphic), you want to use the `:foreign_key` option.  Also, you can't have two associations named the same.  See below for revised code.

```
class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :title, String , :required => true

  key :assigned_user_ids, Array
  has_many :assigned_users, :in => :assigned_user_ids

  key :creator_id , ObjectId
  belongs_to :creator, :class => User
  # userstamps! also accomplishes the above
end

class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key: name, String, :required => true

  has_many :created_tasks, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class => Task

  # inverse of many :in is still in the works
  # see https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/259
  # this is a decent workaround for now
  def assigned_tasks 
    Task.where(:assigned_user_ids => self.id)
  end
end
```

See also:

- [MongoMapper userstamps! documentation](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/userstamps.html)