# MongoDB Nested Design Philosophy

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm creating a system where a company HAS multiple users, customers etc.  I can't decide whether to make "Objects", such as users, a separate collection or embedded documents of a company document.

```
Company (Object) ->
    Users (Object) ->
        Profile (Object) ->
            ...attrs..
        History (Object) ->
            ...attrs...
    Customers ->
        ...attrs...
```

I'm stuck in the relational database mind set right now, and not sure the "proper" way to do it with NoSQL.  What are your thoughts?

What happens when a double embedded document (like company>users->history) gets ridiculously large?

What are some other cons to the embedded document approach (if any)?  Again, I'm biased towards the relational mind-set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB relationships for objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253496/mongodb-relationships-for-objects)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design has some advice on Schema Design, there are also various presentations by members of 10Gen like this one: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/205597/sts/sts-04-2012-mongo-and-nosql-schema.pdf

Given the likely number of users in a company and the likely number of history objects I think you'll probably want a separate collection for each of these.

Answer (score 0):

I can give some general advice here, but in the end it will be up to you as to which approach you take.  The question you need to ask to determine whether to embed or reference is:

What data do you need to return when you fetch a document for most queries?

This can be simple or complex - if 99% of your queries are going to return the same 5 fields, the the answer is obvious.  If you are rarely going to need a piece of data then it's a candidate for a separate collection.  You need a second lookup to fetch that data, and a reference of some sort between them, but the rarity makes that overhead acceptable.

Naturally if your data set and return values are not so clear cut then it becomes a more complicated question.

If a field is needed frequently, but not all of it is needed (say the last 5 entries in history), then store them, fixed size, in the main document and have the rest in a separate collection.  This causes some duplications and complicates your updates but can be a good trade off in terms of speed.

In terms of cons - a large embedded document is not bad per se, but a growing one, particularly one with unbounded growth can be bad.  Every time a document grows there is a chance that it will be too big for its allocated space, which means it will have to be moved.  Not only does this fragment your data somewhat, it can be an expensive operation to move a large document, allocate new space - especially if you are doing it frequently.  The Padding Factor docs explain this pretty well (a padding factor is added when a move is triggered):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor#PaddingFactor-Overview

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to query and get statistics etc. on the related data by itself, then make it embedded which also speeds up querying. If you need to extract this data for some purpose then create new collection(s) for it.