# C# mongodb model like Facebook

Tags: c#, data-modeling, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm working on a project where the MongoDB model will be similar to Facebook. So we all know how FB works, a user "likes" a band/company page, and that user will see all the posts from that page.

Is the below model how I should design this?
If a **Page** has million likes, then each **Post** will have a million sub documents of **Like**. That does not seem right, there must be a better way that I cant think of.

Thanks.

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Like> PersonLikes { get; set; }

}
public class Like
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLiked { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId PageId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<Like> PersonLikes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Nice question, given the fact that things can go viral. I would probably have a like counter instead and then have another collection where the actual like information is stored. Can they be out of sync? of course, there are no transactions, but then do you need to be accurate?

Comment: **>That does not seem right, there must be a better way that I cant think of.**

First of all - yes, it's not right. And MongoDB is definitely not the database for this solution, you're better off with SQL database for this schema. The perfect db for this solution would be graph-db like neo4j

Comment: There are several questions like this on StackOverflow, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253496/mongodb-relationships-for-objects/4253598#4253598

Comment: See also the MongoDB docs which have extensive notes on data models: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take assuming you only want to track likes

```
public class Page
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLikes { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId PageId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLikes { get; set; }
}
```

I would then queue the Reaction (Like or Dislike) for insertion, "sentiment" information doesn't have to be stored in real time, does it?  These are not medications, bank transactions, etc.

```
public class Like
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId ParentId { get; set;}
    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}
```

Queue where? to a collection of Likes. Why not part of the page or post? Because if a post goes viral (as you said even though the majority won't), you may end up with a 1,000,000 likes.  Who is going to browse this information other than an analytic engine?

You also have to ensure a user can only express their reaction only once per item.

Comment: Your `Like` class is missing the Id of the Page or Post that was liked.

Comment: @IanMercer Also changed DateTime to DateTimeOffset .

Comment: Thank you for your response. Each post does not need to be Liked. I just need a user to see the Post.
So in the above example, how would I query the Like collection by UserId "XXXXX" to view all the Post messages?

Comment: @Curtis Notice I suggested PostSentiments and PageSentiments collections both of which have the UserId as well as the corresponding Page or Post through ParentId

Comment: Im sorry I don't know what you mean by PostSentiments and PageSentiments .

Comment: @Curtis simplified to use a single collection for keeping track of all "reactions".

Answer (score 1):

The post only exists on one page so it´s the page that should own the post, not the post owning the page.

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Like> PersonLikes { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
}

public class Like
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLiked { get; set; }
}
```